# Webforms showing source code instead of rendering

Tags: asp.net, webforms, rendering, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm working on a legacy project that used Webforms. There is now a bug occurring on our production servers where a few of the web pages will show source code. I cannot replicate this on our test servers or by debugging it.

If it shows source code it will persistabtly show source code until the in-private/incognito window is closed and a new one is open.

It will occur about 50% of the time (out of 100 recorded tries it failed exactly 50).

This is a screenshots of some of the source code I'm seeing:

[image: source code from AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js]

and

[image]

A commonality between the pages that break are that it uses AjaxControlToolkit, however there are other pages that use AjaxControlToolkit that aren't breaking.

Additionally, when I try to hit these pages they don't hit the page at all. If I'm not signed in they should redirect to the login page and they don't even do that.

Comment: And other projects? Do they work right?
And other browsers?

Comment: The problem occurs across multiple projects and across all browsers.